# Convolve an image several times using for loop opencv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

below is a python code that performs convolution 10 times to an image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/25
img = cv2.imread(r"C:/Users/engjb/.spyder-py3/examples/1.jpeg")





opencvOutput1 = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)


opencvOutput2 = cv2.filter2D(opencvOutput1, -1, kernel)
opencvOutput3 = cv2.filter2D(opencvOutput2, -1, kernel)
opencvOutput4 = cv2.filter2D(opencvOutput3, -1, kernel)
opencvOutput5 = cv2.filter2D(opencvOutput4, -1, kernel)
opencvOutput6 = cv2.filter2D(opencvOutput5, -1, kernel)
opencvOutput7 = cv2.filter2D(opencvOutput6, -1, kernel)
opencvOutput8 = cv2.filter2D(opencvOutput7, -1, kernel)
opencvOutput9 = cv2.filter2D(opencvOutput8, -1, kernel)
opencvOutput10 = cv2.filter2D(opencvOutput9, -1, kernel)

cv2.imshow("res",opencvOutput10)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How can i do this using one single for loop. ( i'm new to python)
I know this must be easy, however i just can't think out of the box

My concept code :

```
for i in rage(0,11):
 output = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)
```

However, this performs the convolution on the same source image in each iteration while i want the convolution to be performed on the output of each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img = cv2.imread( ... )
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    img = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)
```

Notice that is quite different from assigning

```
    output = cv2.filter2D(img, ... )
```

since we want the *next* iteration to use the output.
Without feeding the output back as the next input,
you would be doing just a single convolution.
And you'd be doing it 10x slower,
uselessly computing identical result
another nine times, discarding (over-writing) that work each time.

Comment: I don't know that speed is a real problem here, but convolving the kernel with itself nine times and then filtering the image should produce the same results and would presumably be faster.

Comment: Wow, I really like that, @beaker. I'm concerned that there are some details to finesse, though, as we will need kernel size proportional to number of iterations. Still, the notion of repeating an action on the smaller data structure sounds very winning.